# How to collaborate on swagger documents?

Tags: rest, swagger, swagger-editor, collaborative-editing

Is there a way to collaborate on swagger documents? Putting the yml in a git while having the nice features of the swagger editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is https://swaggerhub.com which is written by the core swagger team.  That provides collaboration features, including organizations and teams, as well as automatically pushing to github.

Comment: Is there any open source free alternative?